# Accessing external resources from a user-defined file path (Java)

Tags: java, windows, file, exe

I've got a Java program which stores/recalls data from a load of .txt files located in my C drive. Currently, the file path for these is hard-coded into my Java program.

I'm now looking to distribute this software and am wondering how can I make it so that the user can specify a file location during installation and then I can point my program to this location without having hard-coded it.

This is pretty standard functionality but I've struggled to find how to achieve it. Can I use relative file paths, i.e. have the .exe for the java program in the same folder as the .txt files, or do I have to use something like Windows registry paths?

Many thanks for your help.

Cheers,
Robin

Comment: I would save myself and the user the trouble. Use "user.home" + your folder as the location. Most of the stuff is stored by default in the home dir: maven, ssh, gradle, shell history. No need to spin it in another way

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to clarify, this is just putting it in the C:/Users/Person folder and fixing that as a known location into which it'll always be installed, right? So this is essentially a better way of hard - coding the "user" root location

Comment: Yes. When you build the path start with the parent directory System.getProperty("user.home"). Don't forget to also use File.separator to avoid conflicts between \ and /

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could I ask if there a reason this method is preferable to simply coding in, for example, C:\Program Files into the software?

Comment: You are using java the moment somebody wants to use your stuff in linux or OS X it will not work. Would you mind to accept the answer?

Comment: That seems fair enough, thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use the system property "user.home" as the root of your path. Most of the stuff installed these days use this system property as the parent dir and a predefined folder. These saves a lot of trouble. Combine that with the File.separator char to avoid further portability issues